# Can I make the children in my cards all have the maximum height among them?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, parent, children

I have 3 separate cards inside a container. I want the children in the cards to all take the height of the tallest sibling in the same row, like the attached image.

[Grid version image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3tDH.png)

As you can see the price div and the lorem ipsum div take the highest value and apply it to all the divs in the same row

I achieved this effect using css grid, but I'm not allowed to use that approach for this particular case, I'll leave the code for that in here however.

https://codesandbox.io/s/same-height-cards-grid-version-vm7vo

I could however achieve this same effect using flexbox but it only works for one element inside the card. If I apply the class which achieves this effect to any other element inside the card, the effect is lost. The code for that is in here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/same-height-cards-94dgf?file=/src/styles.scss

Any solution other than jQuery, grid or html tables is welcomed. Javascript and React hooks are ok.

Stack: React, Gatsby, SASS

Comment: Why can't you use grid? Even IE 10 supports it enough to do this. If you need to support even older/more limited browsers you could use using `display: table-*` or I see nothing wrong with directly using a table in that case. Other than that a JavaScript to loop over the rows and set the heights is relatively trivial to write.

Comment: @RoToRa It's a company project, I can't use grid because this is supposed to be a functionality across several different components and grid css just doesn't cut it for the other components. And yes, your javascript solution is what seems to be the way to go, I've been trying that approach with a higher order component, I'll post if it works.